# Unir o resultados de dois comandos SQL's no H2

Tags: sql, select, h2database

Criei a seguinte `Query`:

```
SELECT s 
FROM SuprimentosPedidos s 
WHERE s.codigoModeloImpressora = :codigoModeloImpressora
AND s.codigoEmpresa = :codigoEmpresa and s.prioridadeSaida = 1 
ORDER BY s.prioridadeSaida, s.suprimento  ASC union
SELECT s 
FROM SuprimentosPedidos s 
WHERE s.codigoModeloImpressora = :codigoModeloImpressora
AND s.codigoEmpresa = :codigoEmpresa and s.prioridadeSaida = 4 and NOT EXISTS (SELECT s 
FROM SuprimentosPedidos s 
WHERE s.codigoModeloImpressora = :codigoModeloImpressora
AND s.codigoEmpresa = :codigoEmpresa and s.prioridadeSaida = 3)
ORDER BY s.prioridadeSaida, s.suprimento  ASC
```

Com o intuito de selecionar do banco tudo que tiver como **prioridade 1** e selecionar o que tiver **prioridade 4** somente quando não existir nada com **prioridade 3** nesse banco, porém ele sempre me retorna somente o que seleciono no meu primeiro *Select*, ou seja se eu coloco assim me retorna apenas os de **prioridade 1** se eu inverto ele me retorna os de **prioridade 4** somente se não há nada no banco de **prioridade 3**. Minha necessidade é unir esses dois resultados, tentei utilizar o `Union` mas não funcionou, teriam alguma ideia de como fazer isso?

Script Create table:

```
    CREATE TABLE suprimentospedidos (
    capacidade character varying(255),
    codigomodeloimpressora integer,
    codigomodelosuprimento integer,
    codigotiposuprimento integer,
    descricao character varying(255),
    statussuprimento character varying(255),
    suprimento character varying(255),
    quantidadesuprimento integer,
    quantidadesuprimentoret integer,
    codigoempresa integer,
    prioridadesaida integer
);
```

Script Insert:

```
insert into public.suprimentospedidos (codigomodeloimpressora, codigomodelosuprimento, suprimento, descricao, capacidade, codigotiposuprimento, statussuprimento, quantidadesuprimento, quantidadesuprimentoret, codigoempresa, prioridadesaida) values
(64,123,'SE260X22G','CILINDRO FOTOCONDUTOR E26X/E36X/E46X 30K (SERVICO)',30000,4,'Ativo',7,0,606,5),
(64,169,'E460X11B','TONER LEXMARK E460 15K',15000,1,'Ativo',17,1,606,2),
(64,172,'X463X11B','TONER LEXMARK X464 15K',15000,1,'Ativo',12,3,606,2),
(64,184,'SE460X11B','TONER LEX E460/X463/X466 15K',15000,2,'Ativo',16,0,606,1),
(64,195,'E260X22G','CILINDRO FOTOCONDUTOR E26X/E36X/E46X 30K',30000,3,'Ativo',2,0,606,6),
(66,123,'SE260X22G','CILINDRO FOTOCONDUTOR E26X/E36X/E46X 30K (SERVICO)',30000,4,'Ativo',7,0,606,5),
(66,169,'E460X11B','TONER LEXMARK E460 15K',15000,1,'Ativo',17,1,606,2),
(66,184,'SE460X11B','TONER LEX E460/X463/X466 15K',15000,2,'Ativo',16,0,606,1),
(66,195,'E260X22G','CILINDRO FOTOCONDUTOR E26X/E36X/E46X 30K',30000,3,'Ativo',2,0,606,6),
(82,155,'50F0Z00','CILINDRO FOTOCONDUTOR LEXMARK 50X 60K',60000,3,'Ativo',58,0,606,6),
(82,163,'60FBX00','TONER LEXMARK 60BX 20K',20000,1,'Ativo',7,2,606,2),
(82,164,'50FBX00','TONER LEXMARK 50BX 10K - MS610,410',10000,1,'Ativo',5,0,606,2),
(82,186,'S60FBX00','TONER LEXMARK 604X 20K',20000,2,'Ativo',17,9,606,1),
(82,193,'S60F4H00','TONER LEXMARK 604H 10K - MX310 / 410 / 511 / 611',10000,2,'Ativo',1,0,606,1),
(82,200,'60FBX0E','TONER LEXMARK 60BXE - SOMENTE SERVIÇOS',20000,1,'Ativo',14,0,606,2),
(83,155,'50F0Z00','CILINDRO FOTOCONDUTOR LEXMARK 50X 60K',60000,3,'Ativo',58,0,606,6),
(83,163,'60FBX00','TONER LEXMARK 60BX 20K',20000,1,'Ativo',7,2,606,2),
(83,164,'50FBX00','TONER LEXMARK 50BX 10K - MS610,410',10000,1,'Ativo',5,0,606,2),
(83,186,'S60FBX00','TONER LEXMARK 604X 20K',20000,2,'Ativo',17,9,606,1),
(83,193,'S60F4H00','TONER LEXMARK 604H 10K - MX310 / 410 / 511 / 611',10000,2,'Ativo',1,0,606,1),
(83,200,'60FBX0E','TONER LEXMARK 60BXE - SOMENTE SERVIÇOS',20000,1,'Ativo',14,0,606,2),
(78,68,'C53034X','KIT FOTOCONDUTOR LEXMARK C532/C534',20000,3,'Ativo',1,0,606,6),
(78,136,'C746H1KG','TONER LEXMARK C748 PRETO 10K',10000,5,'Ativo',4,0,606,4),
(78,137,'C748H1CG','TONER LEXMARK C748 CIANO 10K',10000,5,'Ativo',0,1,606,4),
(78,138,'C748H1MG','TONER LEXMARK C748 MAGENTA 10K',10000,5,'Ativo',3,3,606,4),
(78,139,'C748H1YG','TONER LEXMARK C748 AMARELO 10K',10000,5,'Ativo',0,1,606,4),
(78,140,'C734X77G','CAIXA DE RESIDUOS P/ TONER C736/C748/X738 25K',25000,9,'Ativo',8,0,606,7)
```

Query simplificada:

```
SELECT s 
FROM SuprimentosPedidos s
WHERE s.codigoModeloImpressora = :codigoModeloImpressora
AND s.codigoEmpresa = :codigoEmpresa and s.prioridadeSaida = 6 union all
SELECT s 
FROM SuprimentosPedidos s
WHERE s.codigoModeloImpressora = :codigoModeloImpressora
AND s.codigoEmpresa = :codigoEmpresa and s.prioridadeSaida = 1
ORDER BY s.prioridadeSaida
```

Seguindo a documentação disponível [aqui](http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html) na sessão de `union`

Comment: Quando você rodou o segundo select isolado ele retornou algo?

Comment: @CaiqueRomero, Sim se eu executo qualquer um dos select's separados funciona

Comment: Certo eu fiz algumas mudanças na query e criei um schema para testar, funcionou corretamente. Caso minha resposta não solucione seu problema, será necessário você postar o create table e insert's para sermos mais precisos.

Comment: A coluna codigoEmpresa  não existe em sua tabela.

Comment: @CaiqueRomero desculpe essa table é a que já esta em produção hoje, só um momento logo altero a pergunta com as informações corretas

Answer (score 2):

Separar os select's entre parênteses funciona para o MySql e para o PostgreSQL.

Após descobrir que é H2 Database e que a sytax do Union não funciona igual tentei chegar ao resultado de uma outra forma, utilizando uma tabela temporária:

Exemplo com tabela temporária:

```
CREATE table #suprimentospedidos (
    capacidade character varying(255),
    codigomodeloimpressora integer,
    codigomodelosuprimento integer,
    codigotiposuprimento integer,
    descricao character varying(255),
    statussuprimento character varying(255),
    suprimento character varying(255),
    quantidadesuprimento integer,
    quantidadesuprimentoret integer,
    codigoempresa integer,
    prioridadesaida integer
)

INSERT INTO #suprimentospedidos
SELECT s.*
FROM SuprimentosPedidos s 
WHERE s.codigoModeloImpressora = 83
  AND s.codigoEmpresa = 606
  AND s.prioridadeSaida = 1 
ORDER BY s.prioridadeSaida, s.suprimento  ASC

INSERT INTO #suprimentospedidos
SELECT s.* 
FROM SuprimentosPedidos s
WHERE s.codigoModeloImpressora = 83
  AND s.codigoEmpresa = 606 
  AND s.prioridadeSaida = 6
  AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM SuprimentosPedidos s 
    WHERE s.codigoModeloImpressora = 83
    AND s.codigoEmpresa = 606
    AND s.prioridadeSaida = 3)
ORDER BY s.prioridadeSaida, s.suprimento  ASC

SELECT * FROM #suprimentospedidos s ORDER BY s.prioridadeSaida, s.suprimento  ASC

DROP TABLE #suprimentospedidos
```

Exemplo com `union` separado por parenteses.

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/650c4e/7)

```
(
SELECT s.*
FROM SuprimentosPedidos s 
WHERE s.codigoModeloImpressora = 1
  AND s.codigoEmpresa = 1 
  AND s.prioridadeSaida = 1 
ORDER BY s.prioridadeSaida, s.suprimento  ASC
)
UNION
(
SELECT s.* 
FROM SuprimentosPedidos s
WHERE s.codigoModeloImpressora = 1
  AND s.codigoEmpresa =1 
  AND s.prioridadeSaida = 4 
  AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM SuprimentosPedidos s 
    WHERE s.codigoModeloImpressora = 1
    AND s.codigoEmpresa = 1
    AND s.prioridadeSaida = 3)
ORDER BY s.prioridadeSaida, s.suprimento  ASC
)
```

Comment: Tentei adicionar os parenteses na Query porém quando fui tentar salvar as alterações feitas na Query retornou que houve um erro. Vou alterar minha pergunta

Comment: Qual erro? você viu o link que mandei de exemplo?

Comment: Editei minha pergunta com os scripts de Create Table e de Inserts

Comment: Alterei novamente a pergunta agora com as informações corretas, peço desculpas pelo engano

Comment: Caique austei o insert agora, é para estar correto agora

Comment: Certo, você sabe dizer quais são os valores que vem nas variáveis :codigoModeloImpressora e codigoEmpresa ?

Comment: `:codigoModeloImpressora = 83` e `:codigoEmpresa = 606`

Comment: Eu tentei ajustar a query para deixá-la mais simples mas mesmo assim ela continua me retornando somente o resultado do primeiro select, vou alterar minha pergunta para você ter uma ideia

Comment: O resultado depende dos dados que você tem, no insert que você mostrou Não existe valores de prioridade 4 para o modelo e empresa 83, 606 respectivamente

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66829/discussion-between-r-santos-and-caique-romero).